# Should we stop training discriminator while training generator in CycleGAN tutorial?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

In the code provided by tensorlfow tutorial for CycleGAN, they have trained discriminator and generator simultaneously.

```
def train_step(real_x, real_y):
  # persistent is set to True because the tape is used more than
  # once to calculate the gradients.
  with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    # Generator G translates X -> Y
    # Generator F translates Y -> X.
    
    fake_y = generator_g(real_x, training=True)
    cycled_x = generator_f(fake_y, training=True)

    fake_x = generator_f(real_y, training=True)
    cycled_y = generator_g(fake_x, training=True)

    # same_x and same_y are used for identity loss.
    same_x = generator_f(real_x, training=True)
    same_y = generator_g(real_y, training=True)

    disc_real_x = discriminator_x(real_x, training=True)
    disc_real_y = discriminator_y(real_y, training=True)

    disc_fake_x = discriminator_x(fake_x, training=True)
    disc_fake_y = discriminator_y(fake_y, training=True)

    # calculate the loss
    gen_g_loss = generator_loss(disc_fake_y)
    gen_f_loss = generator_loss(disc_fake_x)
    
    total_cycle_loss = calc_cycle_loss(real_x, cycled_x) + calc_cycle_loss(real_y, cycled_y)
    
    # Total generator loss = adversarial loss + cycle loss
    total_gen_g_loss = gen_g_loss + total_cycle_loss + identity_loss(real_y, same_y)
    total_gen_f_loss = gen_f_loss + total_cycle_loss + identity_loss(real_x, same_x)

    disc_x_loss = discriminator_loss(disc_real_x, disc_fake_x)
    disc_y_loss = discriminator_loss(disc_real_y, disc_fake_y)
  
  # Calculate the gradients for generator and discriminator
  generator_g_gradients = tape.gradient(total_gen_g_loss, 
                                        generator_g.trainable_variables)
  generator_f_gradients = tape.gradient(total_gen_f_loss, 
                                        generator_f.trainable_variables)
  
  discriminator_x_gradients = tape.gradient(disc_x_loss, 
                                            discriminator_x.trainable_variables)
  discriminator_y_gradients = tape.gradient(disc_y_loss, 
                                            discriminator_y.trainable_variables)
  
  # Apply the gradients to the optimizer
  generator_g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_g_gradients, 
                                            generator_g.trainable_variables))

  generator_f_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_f_gradients, 
                                            generator_f.trainable_variables))
  
  discriminator_x_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(discriminator_x_gradients,
                                                discriminator_x.trainable_variables))
  
  discriminator_y_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(discriminator_y_gradients,
                                                discriminator_y.trainable_variables))
```

But while training a GAN network we need to stop training discriminator when we are training generator network.
What's the benefit of using it?

Answer (score 0):

In the GANs, you don't stop training D or G. They are trained simultaneously.
Here they first calculate the gradient values for each network (not to change D or G before calculating the current loss), then update the weights using those.
It's not clear in your question, what's the benefit of what?

Answer (score 0):

For the training to happen in an adversarial way the gradients of the discriminator and generator networks should be updated separately. The discriminator becomes stronger because generator produces more realistic samples and vise versa. If you update these networks together the "adversarial" training is not happening - to the best of my knowledge you are unlikely to obtain pleasing synthetic samples this way.